# Same-sex marriage Egyptian and German immigration

Tags: marriage, german-citizens, egyptian-citizens

My girlfriend and I are thinking of getting married in Germany. We are homosexual. In my country, Egypt, that kind of marriage is not recognized by law and it can be really dangerous for my life.

All I ask is, has anybody any experience with such cases? If anyone has experience I need to know the result of the same cases? Also how do you deal with the German embassy in Egypt? Should it be a secret or not? Is it really true that to marry in Germany I would need a stamp from the German embassy for my birth certificate?

Comment: Is your girlfriend also Egyptian?

Comment: You both need a proof of your own inheritance, as marriage affects the legacy.

Comment: An overview of the process is available here https://www.berlin.de/labo/willkommen-in-berlin/einreise/visumsverfahren/artikel.600163.en.php The documents required will depend on your individual circumstances and the immigration status of your girlfriend in Germany

Comment: @Janka What inheritance?  What legacy?  Can you clarify what you are trying to say here (I'm sure you are trying to make a valid point, but I don't understand it).

Comment: To marry, you need a birth certificate, or inheritance certificate. I think that's the greatest obstacle to Dalia, as it's sure somewhere in a drawer in her father's home and he won't give it to her until he sees the husband. Bummer. And no, you can't marry without that piece of paper in Germany either, as it has to be clear who is in the line of inheritance of your parents. That's your partner, should you die after your parents died (as usual).

Comment: @Janka I agree it sounds like the OP might find it hard to obtain their birth certificate. But are you saying that in Germany the partner of a person automatically stands to inherit from their in-laws and that the heir(s) to an estate have to get an inheritance certificate before the person they’re inheriting from actually dies? That’s not clear from eg https://www.germany.info/us-en/inheritance-estate/922552

Comment: It does not came to me there are multiple meanings to the term *inheritance certificate*. I meant *genealogical certificate*.

Comment: non of all this comments answer my questions sorry

Comment: i am egyptian and my girl friend from germany

Comment: I'm sorry @dalia, but I agree with Martin Bonner: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you asking how to marry your same-sex partner in Germany? Are you asking how to get to Germany to marry? Are you asking how to live in Germany as a same-sex couple after you're married? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: @David: My question was to Janka, not the OP.

Comment: @Janka The only term I recognize in that list is "birth certificate". I have never heard of a genealogical certificate.  The first half of your comment should have been "You both need your birth certificates", and I still can't make sense of what the second part is trying to say.  (It's wrong anyway.  You need the birth certificates because that's what German law says.)

Comment: Can you tell me how you went about this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think German law requires that the marriage is legal according to German law, and according to the law of each spouse's country, in your case according to Egyptian law. And they will want to see a German translation of an Egyptian birth certificate.

You can most likely get around the requirement for the birth certificate if your father holds it and refuses to hand it over, but it may be impossible to get around the requirement that it be legal according to Egyptian law, unless you stay in Germany long enough to acquire German citizenship.

But if you want to get married, you can just walk into the Standesamt where you live (maybe you need to get an appointment first), tell them that you want to get married, and they will tell you all the legal requirements. Because it's their job, because your case makes their day more interesting than most, because the people in that position are generally helpful and quite well-informed about marriage laws about anywhere in the world.

PS. As an alternative you can ask how you would go about entering a civil partnership in Germany and what exactly it means legally. Until quite recently that would have been your only choice in Germany anyway, since same-sex marriage hasn’t been legal in Germany for a long time. If you are lucky then Germany will do this no matter what Egyptian law says. Again, the local Standesamt will know exactly what to do.

PS. Don't know how OP did it - getting German citizenship would be one way. Another way would be getting married in any country in the world that allows it, and whose marriages are recognised in Germany. Getting married in Las Vegas by an Elvis impersonator might actually be workable :-)

Answer (score 1):

All went great: we are married now and live in Germany.

Comment: Congratulations.